# Tensorflow Error: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>, <class 'NoneType'> and Memory Error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, out-of-memory, sparse-matrix

I am encountering two errors when I try testing some text classification samples codes for my dataset using Tensorflow/Keras - https://realpython.com/python-keras-text-classification/

The code runs fine with Sklearn models but when I change it to using Tensorflow/Keras then I encounter these errors.

**Warnings & Errors**

(1) Warning:tensorflow:Falling back from v2 loop because of error: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>, <class'NoneType'>
(2) MemoryError: Unable to allocate 2.19 TiB for an array with shape (930495, 324044) and data type int64

My current version of Tensorflow is 2.0.0.

X is an array of datatype objects - its essentially an array of sentences to be vectorized.

y is an array of binary labels - 0 or 1
array([0, 0, 0, ...., 1, 1, 1], dtype=int64)

After Count vectorization:

X_train is a 930495x324044 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>' with 14680380 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format

X_test is a 310165x324044 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>' with 4837502 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format

What is the issue here? Is it because Tensorflow version 2.0.0 does not support sparse matrix or is my dataset too large after vectorization? How do I resolve this issue?

Would appreciate if someone can advise on this as I tried searching but can't seem t find a way to resolve this.

**Code Snippets**

```
df = joblib.load(classification_labeled_dataset)

X = df['Sentence'].to_numpy()
y = df['Label'].to_numpy()

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, stratify=y, random_state=100)

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
vectorizer.fit(X_train)
X_train = vectorizer.transform(X_train)
X_test = vectorizer.transform(X_test)

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras import layers

features = X_train.shape[1]
model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(10, input_dim=features, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, verbose=False, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), batch_size=10)

loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(X_train, y_train, verbose=False)
```

**Error Traceback**

In [24]: history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, verbose=False, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), batch_size=10)
WARNING:tensorflow:Falling back from v2 loop because of error: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>, <class 'NoneType'>
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input.....>", line 1, in  history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), batch_size=10)

File "D:\Users\user1.conda\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 728, in fit
use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing

File "D:\Users\user1.conda\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 642, in fit
shuffle=shuffle)

File "D:\Users\user1.conda\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 2490, in _standardize_user_data
converted_x.append(_convert_scipy_sparse_tensor(a, b))

File "D:\Users\user1.conda\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 3211, in _convert_scipy_sparse_tensor
return value.toarray()

File "D:\Users\user1.conda\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\compressed.py", line 1025, in toarray
out = self._process_toarray_args(order, out)

File "D:\Users\user1.conda\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py", line 1185, in _process_toarray_args
return np.zeros(self.shape, dtype=self.dtype, order=order)

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 2.19 TiB for an array with shape (930495, 324044) and data type int64

In [25]:

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? So I can copy/paste it and get your error. Also, can you print `y`?

Comment: WIthout traceback it's hard to say where the error occurs (or why).  But if `X_train` is a `csr` sparse matrix, then any attempt to turn it into a 'dense' array, could result in a memory error.  The dense equivalent will be much, much, bigger (all those 0's that 'hidden' in the sparse matrix).  I don't know what `tensorflow` does with such a matrix, but it isn't documented, then it probably can't handle it.  Some `sklearn` code does work  with sparse matrices - as documented.

Comment: have updated the code snippets and error traceback, y is an array of binary labels - 0 or 1 array([0, 0, 0, ...., 1, 1, 1], dtype=int64) ... code runs fine with Sklearn learn models but when I change it to Tensorflow/Keras I encounter these errors. How can I modify my codes so that it can run with Tensorflow/Keras ... need to change the sparse matrix to something else?